# How to get the document count in MongoDB using NodeJS/express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get the count of the `documents` in `MongoDB` collection but I am not getting the count.

Here's what I am trying:

```
//get the invoice count
Routes.route('/invoicescount').get((req, res) => {
  invoicesDB.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
      const c = count;
      res.status(200).send(c);
    }
  });
});
```

It doesn't give any value but in the console it gives this error:

> error found: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value
>   "invoicescount" at path "_id" for model "invoices"

Answer (score 0):

i am using this function for getting the count of every collection:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dbName = "myName";
var port = "27017";
var host = "localhost";

function getNumOfDocs (collectionName, host, port, dbName, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, function (error, db){
        if(error) return callback(error);

        db.collection(collectionName).count({}, function(error, numOfDocs){
            if(error) return callback(error);

            db.close();
            callback(null, numOfDocs);
        });
    }); 
}
```

and i call it:

```
getNumOfDocs("collName", host, port, dbName, function(err, count) {
   if (err) {
       return console.log(err.message);
   }
   console.log('number of documents', count);
});
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: But the name of the variable and how it should be called and where you use it should be in your own code.